# Solving a cylic relations in mySQL Database scheme

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Unfortunatelly I´m not allowd to post an image. So i try to make it clear textual. I want to make a DataBase Scheme to save Trainingschedules.

I got some Entities.

Training, TrainingSchedule, Exercise, Pause

Relations are like this:

```
   -------------1 Training 1----------
  n|                 |1              |n
Exercise             |             Pause
  1|                 |n              |1
   --------n TrainingSchedule n-------
```

So.. A Training got a bunlde of Exercises, and Pauses, 
The Arrangement... when to DO which Exercise, or Pause is stated in the schedule, which belongs to the actual training. One Exercise or Pause can appear as often as desired in the schedule...

I came up with a dataBase-Scheme where I implemented this cyclic relations - but someone told me that this could lead me into troubles.

Any ideas how to solve this cyclic realtions clean and nicely? (I allready found a dirty solution myself - but somehow my stomach don´t like the idea...)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have these circular references if you reorganize your schema.  To give you a step in the right direction, consider this:

If a training record can have many training schedules, and each training schedule can have many pauses and exercises, then a training record can have many pauses and/or exercises and the relationship between them can be inferred by appropriately querying the data in a training schedule record set thus a direct connection from exercise to training or pause to training is not necessary.

If you use this line of thinking then your relationships would look something like:

- Training table

  - 1->M Training Schedule

    - 1->M Exercises
    - 1->M Pauses

Another approach would be to add another layer to the describing training schedule such that you have two tables to describe the schedule:

- Training schedule - contains data on the actual training schedule itself
- Schedule elements - contains foreign keys from training schedule and exercises/pauses table.

In this approach, you will not require the duplication of data in the training table if your training table contains fields that describe the schedule itself (i.e. a session field or a location field) and you set yourself up for a more scalable design.

Also ask yourself the question of what kind of records will exist in the pauses table.  From your description it seems that a pause in the schedule is essentially a period where no exercise is occurring.  If this is the case, it may make sense to handle these pauses with a different approach since an exercise and a pause are essentially describing the contents of a time slot - but the description of these time slots are coming from two separate tables (thus will most likely have two separate definitions). This will most certainly cause issues when attempting to query information from the correct source.

Comment: First of all Thank you for your time!!! 

The first idea you offered did also cross my mind. But I will lose the connection to Exercises/Pauses which are not used (at the moment). For example  - I´m thinking in "LEGO bricks"...

...a Training got Excersises A,B and C
....a Training got Pauses a,b, and c
.....a Training got Schedules (more favorable ScheduleEntries) where the order A, b, A, B, c, B ... is stated. 
So if I cut the relation to Trainings 'C' and 'a' will be lost.... Sorry for the formatting - I also could send you an email ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the statement "So if I cut the relation to Trainings 'C' and 'a' will be lost".  If you are worried about not being able to link an exercise (say exercise B) and / or a pause (say pause X) to a record in training this will not be true, UNLESS you have not used exercise B or pause X at all.  As soon as you use exercise B you will be able to query your training schedule table for all schedules that use exercise B.  As part of the query results you will have a training ID to finalize the link from exercise to training. Is this what you are concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I think I will try a solution like this:

```
                 EXERCISE
                    1
                    |
                    1
TRAINING 1------n BLOCK 1--------n SCHEDULE
                    1
                    |
                    1
                  PAUSE
```

No - loops - no repitions of data.... hopefully anybody else got same problems. 
[Here](http://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back) is also a nice